# OSX Mavericks - Enabling Custom DHCP Options

Tags: macos, network

I am using a new MAC running OSX Mavericks with a solaris ISC DHCPD server.

I have setup some additional options on the DHCPD server but it is my understanding that most DHCP clients don't request all DHCP Options.

I'm trying to ascertain how I configure OSX to send a DHCP request that includes these additional options.

My overall goal here is to issue option 26 which stipulates an MTU size.

Answer (score 1):

As per: https://discussions.apple.com/message/26472927#26472927

This was the exact answer.

The file has moved to:

/System/Library/SystemConfiguration/IPConfiguration.bundle/Contents/Info.plist

Answer (score 0):

now that SIP is in play, is there a way to add additional options to DHCP discover requests?